# How to embed a promise in a node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have tried to embed a promise in node.js module but I can't return the value in result and the second promise code block is ran before the promise in the module. However, it should be the opposite. The code after the "then should ran after the promise in the NodeJs module. Also, I was forced to use global variables and I know it is not a good approach.

auth4.js

```
module.exports = 
    new Promise ((resolve,error)=>{

    setTimeout(function(){ 
        ok = "should appear last too"; 
        console.log("called in module and should be first", 
        JSON.stringify(credentials));
    }, 10000);

    resolve(ok);
    error(ok);
});
```

main.js

```
global.ok = "";
global.credentials = {username:'jojo',password:'test123'};
require('./auth4.js').then(function(result){
    console.log("should be displayed last",result);
});
```

Comment: Why? Anyway, resolve is right after the timeout. You are calling resolve before the timeout completes.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't call both `resolve` and `error` - which, btw. should be named `reject`

Comment: You probably want your `resolve` inside of your `setTimeout` function. And you don't need to call your `reject` (`error` here) because you have no conditions for failure.

Comment: It is important to know that a `setTimeout` just queues a function to be ran later. It doesn't really block any of the code after itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think you are looking for

```
// auth4.js
module.exports = function(credentials) {
    return new Promise((resolve, error) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("called in module and should be first", JSON.stringify(credentials));
            resolve("should appear last too");
        }, 10000);
    });
};
```

```
// main.js
require('./auth4.js')({username:'jojo',password:'test123'}).then(function(ok) {
    console.log("should be displayed last", ok);
});
```